# Executing Multiple Lines in Python

Tags: python

When Python is first installed, the default setting executes users' code input line-by-line. But sometimes I need to write programs that execute multiple lines at once. Is there a setting in Python where I can change the code execution to one block at once?

```
>>> if (n/2) * 2 == n:;
        print 'Even';
        else: print 'Odd'
```

Error:

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

When I tried to run the above code, I got an invalid syntax error on the *else*.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to write an application featuring concurrency. There are a number of ways to do this but the solution really depends on the problem domain. Can you provide some context?

Comment: Python programs very nearly *never* contain semicolons (`;`) (as part of the language, outside a string). If you're using semicolons, you're probably doing something wrong. Do not use semicolons unless you're absolutely sure you know why you need one.

Comment: I guess semicolons in python are only useful when you do code-golf

Comment: Ah... **that** kind of multiple lines at once :-D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your indentation is wrong. Try this:

```
>>> if (n/2) * 2 == n:
...     print 'Even'
... else: print 'Odd'
```

Also you might want to write it on four lines:

```
>>> if (n/2) * 2 == n:
...     print 'Even'
... else:
...     print 'Odd'
```

Or even just one line:

```
>>> print 'Even' if (n/2) * 2 == n else 'Odd'
```

Answer (score 1):

One step towards the solution is to remove the semicolon after the `if`:

```
if True:; print 'true'; print 'not ok'; # syntax error!

if True: print 'true'; print 'ok'; # ok
```

You cannot have an `else` in the same line because it would be ambiguous:

```
if True: print 't'; if True: print 'tt; else: ... # <- which if is that else for??
```

It is also clearly stated in the [docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#compound-statements) that you need a `DEDENT` before the else statement can start.

Comment: It's not actually ok at all to use semicolons after any expression;

Comment: @hyperboreean: quoting the docs: "A suite can be one or more **semicolon-separated** simple statements on the same line as the header, following the header’s colon, or it can be one or more indented statements on subsequent lines."

Comment: see my answer for python >=2.5

Answer (score 0):

Since python 2.5 you can do [one line ifs](http://amix.dk/blog/post/19291)

```
print ('Even' if n % 2 == 0 else 'Odd')
```

Still to answer your question you can either:
1. enter the code properly without syntax errors and your blocks will be executed as blocks regardless if they span multiple lines or not, even in interactive shell. See tutorials in [dive into python](http://www.diveintopython.net/)
2. write code in the script and execute that script using either command line or some IDE ([idle](http://docs.python.org/library/idle.html), [eclipse](http://pydev.org/), etc..)

One of the idea behind python is to prefer multiple lines and to aim for uniform formatting of source, so what you try to do is not pythonic, you should not aim to cram multiple statements into single line unless you have a good reason.

Answer (score 0):

```
print n % 2 == 0 and 'Even' or 'Odd'
```

:-)